# Android - Firebase rename file(SHA-1) before upload

Tags: android, firebase, encryption, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

Everyone, I need to rename file before uploading to Firebase Storage 
with multiple image upload and encode to *sha-1*  **(imagename + uid + current time)**:

> 915731b2094b1cb23c1b176ef8633947f737804b,fdf15718d6d988ce188bdc8debcb7d5998229db3

Multi Select Image i get from this link https://github.com/donglua/PhotoPicker

Mainboard Post Class (Class To Post to Firebase Storage and stamp to Firebase Database but now i don't have to put sha1hash to Firebase Database

```
   private static final String TAG = "MainboardPost";
private static final int MAP_REQUEST_CODE = 334;
private static final int ADD_PHOTO_REQUEST = 335;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private TextView cancle;
private Mainboard post;
private PhotoAdapter photoAdapter;
private ArrayList<String> selectedPhotos = new ArrayList<>();
Button img_btn,map_btn,removeMapBtn;
RelativeLayout layout_img , layout_map ;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
EditText header , body;

private UploadTask mUploadtask;

ImageButton addMapBtn;
FrameLayout frameLayout;

private FirebaseStorage storageRef;
private StorageReference mStorage , folderRef;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

// รับค่าlat lon เพื่อโพส
private String loc_latlon;
private String loc_address;

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

GoogleMap map;
Marker mMarker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_mainbard_post);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_post); //Custom toolbar
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);  //  Class Actionbar ให้ใช้ Toolbar แทนของระบบ
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); // ซ่อนชื่อแอพบน Toolbar


    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    mStorage = storageRef.getReference();
    folderRef = mStorage.child("mainboard");


    frameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.map_frame);
    removeMapBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.remove_btn);
    addMapBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.addmap_btn);
    layout_img = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_add_photo);
    layout_map = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_add_map);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.addimg_view);
    header = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.topic);
    body = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.detail);
    photoAdapter = new PhotoAdapter(MainboardPost.this, selectedPhotos);

    img_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add_img);
    img_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            layout_img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            layout_map.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
    map_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add_map);
    map_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            layout_map.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            layout_img.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    });

    cancle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_cancle);
    cancle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });


    addMapBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainboardPost.this, MapsActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, MAP_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });

    removeMapBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            frameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            addMapBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(4, OrientationHelper.VERTICAL));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(photoAdapter);

    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClick(MainboardPost.this,
            new RecyclerItemClick.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                    if (photoAdapter.getItemViewType(position) == PhotoAdapter.TYPE_ADD) {
                        PhotoPicker.builder()
                                .setPhotoCount(PhotoAdapter.MAX)
                                .setShowCamera(true)
                                .setPreviewEnabled(false)
                                .setSelected(selectedPhotos)
                                .start(MainboardPost.this, REQUEST_CODE);
                    } else {
                        PhotoPreview.builder()
                                .setPhotos(selectedPhotos)
                                .setCurrentItem(position)
                                .start(MainboardPost.this, REQUEST_CODE);
                    }
                }
            }));

    setUpGoogleMap();

}

//Menu Item ขวามือสุดของ Toolbar
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_post, menu);
    return true;
}

private void setUpGoogleMap() {
    if (new GooglePlayServiceCheck().isGooglePlayInstalled(MainboardPost.this)) {

        SupportMapFragment map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapView2));
        map.getMapAsync(this);//after getting map call async method, this method will call onMapReady(GoogleMap map) method
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MAP_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                //Location Fetched
                double lat = data.getDoubleExtra("location_lat", 0);
                double lng = data.getDoubleExtra("location_lng", 0);

                loc_latlon = lat + "," + lng;

                Log.e("Selected Lat-lng", lat + " - " + lng);
                frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                addMapBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //Here after getting lat lng add marker to ur google map using fetched lat lng
                setPickedLocationOverMap(lat, lng);
                //
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_CODE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK &&
                    (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE || requestCode == PhotoPreview.REQUEST_CODE)) {
                List<String> photos = null;
                if (data != null) {
                    photos = data.getStringArrayListExtra(PhotoPicker.KEY_SELECTED_PHOTOS);
                }
                selectedPhotos.clear();

                if (photos != null) {

                    selectedPhotos.addAll(photos);
                }
                photoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            break;
    }
}

private void setPickedLocationOverMap(double lat, double lng) {
    // Needs to call MapsInitializer before doing any CameraUpdateFactory calls
    MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getApplicationContext());
    // Updates the location and zoom of the MapView
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat, lng), 17);
    if (map != null)
        map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    this.map = googleMap;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    submitPost();
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.button_upload_resume:
            Helper.mProgressDialog.show();
            mUploadtask.resume();
            break;
    }
}

private void submitPost() {


    final String title = header.getText().toString().trim();
    final String detail = body.getText().toString().trim();

    if (loc_latlon == null){
        loc_latlon = "";
    }

    if (loc_address == null){
        loc_address = "";
    }

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(title) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(detail)){
        final String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        mDatabase.child("user").child(userId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                if (user == null){
                    Log.e(TAG, "User " + userId + " is unexpectedly null");
                    Toast.makeText(MainboardPost.this,
                            "Error: could not fetch user.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }else {
                    writenewpost(title , detail , loc_latlon , loc_address);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.w(TAG, "getUser:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
            }
        });
    }
    for (String imagePath : selectedPhotos){
        Uri file =  Uri.fromFile(new File(imagePath));
        StorageReference imageRef = folderRef.child(file.getLastPathSegment());
        mUploadtask = imageRef.putFile(file);

    }

}

private void writenewpost(String mbTitle , String mbBody, String mbLocation , String mbAddress )

{

    String key = mDatabase.child("mainboard").push().getKey();
    PostMainboard mainboard_post = new PostMainboard(mbTitle, mbBody , mbLocation , mbAddress);

    Map<String, Object>postvalue = mainboard_post.toMap();
    Map<String, Object>childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
    childUpdates.put("/mainboard/" + key , postvalue);

    mDatabase.updateChildren(childUpdates);
}
```

Mainboard Post Model

```
public String mb_address;
public String mb_body;
public String mb_location;
public String mb_pic;
public String mb_title ;

public PostMainboard(){

}

public PostMainboard( String mb_title ,String mb_body,String mb_location,String mb_address , String mb_pic)

{
    this.mb_address = mb_address;
    this.mb_body = mb_body;
    this.mb_location = mb_location;
    this.mb_pic = mb_pic;
    this.mb_title = mb_title;
}

@Exclude
public Map<String , Object> toMap(){
    HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
    result.put("mb_title" , mb_title);
    result.put("mb_body" , mb_body);
    result.put("mb_location" , mb_location);
    result.put("mb_address" , mb_address);
    result.put("mb_pic" , mb_pic);
    return result;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Below is a support class for creating a SHA-1 certificate. This maybe helpful for you .**

**1.Create a `class` named `SHA1Hash.java` and paste below code. Imports necessary package.**

```
public class SHA1Hash {

    private static String convertToHex(byte[] data) {
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte b : data) {
            int halfbyte = (b >>> 4) & 0x0F;
            int two_halfs = 0;
            do {
                buf.append((0 <= halfbyte) && (halfbyte <= 9) ? (char) ('0' + halfbyte) : (char) ('a' + (halfbyte - 10)));
                halfbyte = b & 0x0F;
            } while (two_halfs++ < 1);
        }
        return buf.toString();
    }

    public static String SHA1(String text) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        md.update(text.getBytes("iso-8859-1"), 0, text.length());
        byte[] sha1hash = md.digest();
        return convertToHex(sha1hash);
    }
}
```

**2. Use this call method as below to create SHA1 Certificate Using datetime and your necessary String value .**

```
        public static String getDateTimeHash(String uid, String imageName){
            final String HASH_KEY = uid+imageName;
            String hashString = "";
            String timeInMilliSeconds = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
            try {
               hashString =  SHA1Hash.SHA1(timeInMilliSeconds.concat(HASH_KEY));
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.d("Utils","Hash Value is "+hashString);
            return  hashString ; 
        }
```

**Edited the uses method according your need . You can pass `imageName+uid+currentTime` as `String`  as the method takes `String` type of value**

**Your final code :**

```
private static final String TAG = "MainboardPost";
private static final int MAP_REQUEST_CODE = 334;
private static final int ADD_PHOTO_REQUEST = 335;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private TextView cancle;
private Mainboard post;
private PhotoAdapter photoAdapter;
private ArrayList<String> selectedPhotos = new ArrayList<>();
Button img_btn,map_btn,removeMapBtn;
RelativeLayout layout_img , layout_map ;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
EditText header , body;

private UploadTask mUploadtask;

ImageButton addMapBtn;
FrameLayout frameLayout;

private FirebaseStorage storageRef;
private StorageReference mStorage , folderRef;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

// รับค่าlat lon เพื่อโพส
private String loc_latlon;
private String loc_address;

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

GoogleMap map;
Marker mMarker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_mainbard_post);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_post); //Custom toolbar
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);  //  Class Actionbar ให้ใช้ Toolbar แทนของระบบ
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); // ซ่อนชื่อแอพบน Toolbar


    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    mStorage = storageRef.getReference();
    folderRef = mStorage.child("mainboard");


    frameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.map_frame);
    removeMapBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.remove_btn);
    addMapBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.addmap_btn);
    layout_img = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_add_photo);
    layout_map = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_add_map);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.addimg_view);
    header = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.topic);
    body = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.detail);
    photoAdapter = new PhotoAdapter(MainboardPost.this, selectedPhotos);

    img_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add_img);
    img_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            layout_img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            layout_map.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
    map_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add_map);
    map_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            layout_map.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            layout_img.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    });

    cancle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_cancle);
    cancle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });


    addMapBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainboardPost.this, MapsActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, MAP_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });

    removeMapBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            frameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            addMapBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(4, OrientationHelper.VERTICAL));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(photoAdapter);

    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClick(MainboardPost.this,
            new RecyclerItemClick.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                    if (photoAdapter.getItemViewType(position) == PhotoAdapter.TYPE_ADD) {
                        PhotoPicker.builder()
                                .setPhotoCount(PhotoAdapter.MAX)
                                .setShowCamera(true)
                                .setPreviewEnabled(false)
                                .setSelected(selectedPhotos)
                                .start(MainboardPost.this, REQUEST_CODE);
                    } else {
                        PhotoPreview.builder()
                                .setPhotos(selectedPhotos)
                                .setCurrentItem(position)
                                .start(MainboardPost.this, REQUEST_CODE);
                    }
                }
            }));

    setUpGoogleMap();

}

//Menu Item ขวามือสุดของ Toolbar
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_post, menu);
    return true;
}

private void setUpGoogleMap() {
    if (new GooglePlayServiceCheck().isGooglePlayInstalled(MainboardPost.this)) {

        SupportMapFragment map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapView2));
        map.getMapAsync(this);//after getting map call async method, this method will call onMapReady(GoogleMap map) method
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MAP_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                //Location Fetched
                double lat = data.getDoubleExtra("location_lat", 0);
                double lng = data.getDoubleExtra("location_lng", 0);

                loc_latlon = lat + "," + lng;

                Log.e("Selected Lat-lng", lat + " - " + lng);
                frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                addMapBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //Here after getting lat lng add marker to ur google map using fetched lat lng
                setPickedLocationOverMap(lat, lng);
                //
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_CODE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK &&
                    (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE || requestCode == PhotoPreview.REQUEST_CODE)) {
                List<String> photos = null;
                if (data != null) {
                    photos = data.getStringArrayListExtra(PhotoPicker.KEY_SELECTED_PHOTOS);
                }
                selectedPhotos.clear();

                if (photos != null) {

                    selectedPhotos.addAll(photos);
                }
                photoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            break;
    }
}

private void setPickedLocationOverMap(double lat, double lng) {
    // Needs to call MapsInitializer before doing any CameraUpdateFactory calls
    MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getApplicationContext());
    // Updates the location and zoom of the MapView
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat, lng), 17);
    if (map != null)
        map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    this.map = googleMap;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    submitPost();
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.button_upload_resume:
            Helper.mProgressDialog.show();
            mUploadtask.resume();
            break;
    }
}

private void submitPost() {


    final String title = header.getText().toString().trim();
    final String detail = body.getText().toString().trim();
final String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

    if (loc_latlon == null){
        loc_latlon = "";
    }

    if (loc_address == null){
        loc_address = "";
    }

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(title) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(detail)){

        mDatabase.child("user").child(userId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                if (user == null){
                    Log.e(TAG, "User " + userId + " is unexpectedly null");
                    Toast.makeText(MainboardPost.this,
                            "Error: could not fetch user.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }else {
                    writenewpost(title , detail , loc_latlon , loc_address);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.w(TAG, "getUser:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
            }
        });
    }
    for (String imagePath : selectedPhotos){
        Uri file =  Uri.fromFile(new File(imagePath));
         String imageName=imagePath.substring(imagePath.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
         Log.d("ImageName" , imageName) ; 
         String hashImageName = getDateTimeHash(userId, imageName); 
         Log.d("HashImageName" , hashImageName); 
        StorageReference imageRef = folderRef.child(hashImageName);
        mUploadtask = imageRef.putFile(file);

    }

}

private void writenewpost(String mbTitle , String mbBody, String mbLocation , String mbAddress )

{

    String key = mDatabase.child("mainboard").push().getKey();
    PostMainboard mainboard_post = new PostMainboard(mbTitle, mbBody , mbLocation , mbAddress);

    Map<String, Object>postvalue = mainboard_post.toMap();
    Map<String, Object>childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
    childUpdates.put("/mainboard/" + key , postvalue);

    mDatabase.updateChildren(childUpdates);
}

public static String getDateTimeHash(String uid, String imageName){
            final String HASH_KEY = uid+imageName;
            String hashString = "";
            String timeInMilliSeconds = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
            try {
               hashString =  SHA1Hash.SHA1(timeInMilliSeconds.concat(HASH_KEY));
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.d("Utils","Hash Value is "+hashString);
            return  hashString ; 
        }
```

Hope this is helpful for you. Thanks

Comment: Thank for reply but i'm newbie for this i create the class and how can i use in my code

Comment: ok let me check your code and get the imageName and uid for you. @C.Junior  where can i get imageName & uid in your class .

Comment: I edited the function parameter, Now just use this method by passing your uid and imageName , it will gives a sha1 key in return as a String. 
You can use this function in any class or activity your want.

Comment: C.Junior did you able to to use the solution. Please let me know if you face any problem .

Comment: Sorry sir i will update my code with problem and the file name i can't find it i think use same as phone image name

Comment: i create the sha1hash class and use in my post code but  i dont know how to use in my code

Comment: Can you specify where can i get your uid and imageName , i didn't see any variable name like in your given code .

Comment: Please copy &  paste your complete code with individual Class or Activity name (Whole calss & Activity Code ) . I can give you a solution . or use https://pastebin.com/ and comment the url .

Comment: C.Junior  Please check the edited  answer . I added the method and code in you Activity class. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Piash Sarkar  in line for loop post what is the path and userId

  String imageName=imagePath.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
  String hashImageName = getDateTimeHash(userId, imageName);

Comment: I changes the userId variable scope and edited the answer again. Please use edited code. 
final String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

userId is currrentUserId from the firebaseAuth . 

imagePath is your ImagePath .

Comment: it return  null on StorageReference imageRef = folderRef.child(hashImageName);

Comment: Wow got it i can post with sha1hash and secound how can i do all file name with sha1hash to String format like "A1,A2,A3,A4,A5"